# C++ How to pass static function as a callback if it is declared in a separate file?

Tags: c++, sqlite, callback, function-pointers

### Context

In the separate file in class `Utils`, there are two static functions: `quote_sql()` and `default_callback()`. Both functions are working fine if called directly. However if you pass `default_callback()` as a pointer to `sqlite3_exec`, it won't be invoked.

### Code

```cpp
// sqlite_common.hpp
class Utils {
    
public:
    static std::string quote_sql(const std::string str)
    {
        std::string quote = "'";
        std::string result = quote + str + quote;
        return result;
    }

    static int default_callback(void* used, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
    {
        std::cout << "Callback is called.\n";
        bool* status = static_cast<bool*>(used);
        *status = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
};
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
void signup_func()
{
    // quote_sql() is working as it should
    std::string sql = 
        "INSERT INTO User (Login, Password) VALUES (" 
        +  Utils::quote_sql(login) + "," + Utils::quote_sql(password) + ");";
    
    // here default callback is never called even when it should have been
    char* zErrMsg; 
    bool status = false; // status is just the first argument of callback
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), Utils::default_callback, &status, &zErrMsg);
    
    // however this will output "Callback is called."
    default_callback(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // this also doesn't work
    auto callback = &Utils::default_callback;
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, &status, &zErrMsg);

    // declaring default_callback outside of a class doesn't work either
    // in fact that's how it was in the first place
    // the only case when it works is when I define callback in main.cpp
}
```

### What I want?

I want to be able to store `default_callback()` in a separate file and pass it into functions around the program with it executing where it should.

## Edit

This code works somehow. Similar situation: static callback function is in a seperate file passed by pointer but works just fine.

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

#include "callback.hpp"

int do_action(int a, int b, int(*action)(int, int))
{
    return action(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    auto callback = &sum;
   
    // will output 4 as it should
    std::cout << do_action(2, 2, callback) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

```
// callback.hpp

static int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: What result code are you getting from `sqlite3_exec`? From the looks of it, you are using it correctly and if the query succeeded, your `callback` should be invoked.

Comment: @JanSchultke `sqlite3_exec` executes `sql` statement. If execution is successful it indeed calls the callback function. In my case execution is successful and it adds entry to the User table as it should but callback is never called due to it being invisible from `main.cpp`.

Comment: @JanSchultke If you are still looking into this I've added another peace of code that somehow works yet doing things in a similar way.

Comment: @trofchik the callback code you have shown is perfectly fine, the callback function is NOT "invisible from main.cpp", so your diagnosis is wrong. Something else must be going on. Either the SQL is not producing the result set you are expecting (and FYI, an `INSERT` does not return any rows), or there is an error that you are not handling.

Comment: @trofchik On a side note, your `quote_sql()` function is insufficient to protect against SQL Injection attacks, as you are not [escaping embedded quotes](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) inside the string. You should be using [prepared statements](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) instead of quoting strings manually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've experimented with other pieces of code I have and your point about `INSERT` not returning any rows is probably the reason why callback is never called. Thank you.